# When is faster to use batch operations on JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, batch-file

I have a piece of code that executes about 500,000 inserts on a database. It's now done in a loop calling PreparedStatement's executeUpdate at each iteration. Would it be faster to add all 500,000 inserts to a batch and and call executeBatch just once?

Comment: What does "better" mean?  Simpler?  Faster?  Easier to maintain?  Less use of network?  Easier to rollback in the event of a problem?

Comment: @S.Lott: it's pretty safe to assume "better" means "faster" in 99% of questions about SQL.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: Interesting observation.  How do you know that?  Is it true for this question?  How do you know *that*?

Comment: @S.Lott: Of course, in general "better" is not equal "faster". But other assumptions for "better" in this context are not really obvious. Faster is obvious when talking about JDBC/batch/prepared statement and 500,000 inserts. By keeping questions concise and not explaining obvious facts we do a great deal of favor to other users.

Comment: It was true for my question. Sorry i didn't make myself clear enough. I meant faster!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be much faster. make sure you turn autoCommit off first, otherwise you get no performance benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Using PreparedStatement in combination with batch update facility yields most efficient results (from [Sun JDBC doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html)):

```
// turn off autocommit
con.setAutoCommit(false);

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO employees VALUES (?, ?)");

stmt.setInt(1, 2000);
stmt.setString(2, "Kelly Kaufmann");
stmt.addBatch();

stmt.setInt(1, 3000);
stmt.setString(2, "Bill Barnes");
stmt.addBatch();

// submit the batch for execution
int[] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
```

Answer (score 1):

500.000 is way too much to add at once. Remember those records are kept in memory and sent at once.Add them in batches of a few thousands, I didn't notice any improvement between 1000 and 10000 rows in a batch(with MySQL) but I presume some other factors counts.

Comment: it could quite feasible for small example with prepared statement. but it really depends, i agree...